# Are my steps to prove that a particular inequality holds correct?

Tags: probability, inequality

Let $X$ be a continous RV where $X \sim F(\cdot)$ on $[0,1]$ with strictly positive density $f(\cdot)$. Furthermore, suppose that $\hat{x} \in (0,1)$. I want to show that the following inequality holds (or find a counterexample that it does not hold and then find some restrictions on $F(\cdot)$ such that it does hold):
\begin{align*}
F(\hat{x})\cdot \int\limits_{0}^{1}F(x)\hspace{0.5ex}dx > \int\limits_{0}^{\hat{x}}F(x)\hspace{0.5ex}dx
\end{align*}
My steps so far:
\begin{align*}
F(\hat{x})\cdot \int\limits_{0}^{1}F(x)\hspace{0.5ex}dx > \int\limits_{0}^{\hat{x}}F(x)\hspace{0.5ex}dx 
\Leftrightarrow \frac{\int\limits_{0}^{1}F(x)\hspace{0.5ex}dx}{F(1)} >  \frac{\int\limits_{0}^{\hat{x}}F(x)\hspace{0.5ex}dx}{F(\hat{x})} \\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \big\vert_{x=1}\hspace{0.5ex} ln \left(\int\limits_{0}^{x}F(u)\hspace{0.5ex}du\right)} > \frac{1}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\big\vert_{x=\hat{x}}\hspace{0.5ex} ln \left(\int\limits_{0}^{x}F(u)\hspace{0.5ex}du\right)}
\end{align*}

Define the function A(x) =  $\int\limits_{0}^{x}F(u)\hspace{0.5ex}du$ and note that it is strictly increasing and stricly convex in $x\in[0,1)$. Since $A(x)$ is stricly increasing in $x$, $ln(A(x))$ is also strictly increasing and we finally need to show that:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\big\vert_{x=\hat{x}}\hspace{0.5ex} ln (A(x)) > \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\big\vert_{x=1}\hspace{0.5ex} ln (A(x))
\end{align*}
Now, obviously the inequality holds if $ln(A(x))$ is strictly concave in x. Therefore, If we show that A(x) is log concave, we are done. Now, this is the step where I am struggling with. Does somebody have an Idea on what additional assumption i could impose on $F(x)$ such that $A(x) = \int\limits_{0}^{x}F(u)du$ is log concave in x?

Thank you!

Edit: I just realized that I mixed up the definitions of Quasi concavity and log concavity. Of course, not every strictly increasing function is log-concave. Sorry for that stupid mistake. I deleted that section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I might have come up with a solution.

In order to show that A(x) is log-concave, for any $x',x'' ,\lambda \in (0,1)$ and $\tilde{x} = \lambda x' + (1-\lambda)x''$ we need to show that:
\begin{align*}
\int\limits_{0}^{\tilde{x}}F(u)\hspace{0.5ex} du > \left(\int\limits_{0}^{x'} F(u)\hspace{0.5ex} du\right)^\lambda \left(\int\limits_{0}^{x''} F(u)\hspace{0.5ex} du \right)^{1-\lambda}
\end{align*}

Assuming that $F(\cdot)$ is log concave, doesn't it follow from Prekopa (1971) and Borel (1975) that $A(x) = \int\limits_{0}^{x} F(u)\hspace{0.5ex} du$ must be log concave too?